# Primefaces Extension 11 NoClassDefFoundError EditorOptions

Tags: jsf, jboss, primefaces-extensions

Runtime error when running primefaces-extension 11 component monacoEditor on JBoss EAP 7.3

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Cant instantiate class: org.primefaces.extensions.component.monacoeditor.MonacoEditorInline.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.newThing(ApplicationImpl.java:1738)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1893)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/extensions/model/monacoeditor/EditorOptions
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.monacoeditor.MonacoEditorBase.<init>(MonacoEditorBase.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.extensions.component.monacoeditor.MonacoEditorInline.<init>(MonacoEditorInline.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
```

I also use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>resources-monacoeditor</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Primefaces 11, Primefaces-exstension 11.0.4, resources-monacoeditor 11.0.4, mojarra 2.1.28, Jboss EAP 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem. Our project is an EAR and we use monaco editor and resources-monacoeditor in one of the module of the EAR that produce a WAR. When put the resources-monacoeditor library also in the main pom (pom of the EAR, parent pom) error is solved